# crud codeigniter default value

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

Hi all I have a site develop in codeigniter with crud.
Into my insert view I have a select where I want to put in default a value, I have done int his mode (the name of the filed is id_company)

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$state_crud = $crud->getState();
$crud->set_relation('id_company','company','name_company');
$crud->set_relation('id_plant','plant','name_plant');
$crud->set_relation('id_order','order','name_order');
$crud->field_type('id_plant','dropdown', array('0' => '') );
$crud->unset_print();
$crud->unset_export();
$crud->unset_delete();
$data['name_company'] = $company[0]['name_company'];
$data['id_company'] = $company[0]['id'];

$crud->callback_edit_field('id_company',array($this,'edit_field_callback_id_company_add'));
```

and the callback is:

```
function edit_field_callback_id_company_add($value, $primary_key){
    $company = $this->Company_model->getCompany($value);
    return '<div id="field-id_company" class="readonly_label">'.$company->name_company.'</div>';
}
```

my model function

```
function getCompany($id_company, $select = ''){
        if( isset($id_company) && $id_company > 0 ) : 
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            if( $select ) $this->CI->db->select($select);
            $this->CI->db->where('id', $id_company);
            $query = $this->CI->db->get_where($this->company_table);
            return $query->result_array();
        endif;
        return FALSE;
    }
```

i have seen that crud  insert a select with name field-id_company_czhn I have try to insert it but nothing.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Maybe if you try to add an if statement it should work. So in your case perhaps this will work fine for you:

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$state_crud = $crud->getState();

if ($state_crud == 'edit' || $state_crud == 'update') {
    $crud->callback_edit_field('id_company',array($this,'edit_field_callback_id_company_add'));
} else {
    $crud->set_relation('id_company','company','name_company');
}

...
```

---

The logic that you are using the callback is wrong. So in your case you need something like this:

```
 $crud->callback_edit_field('id_company',
                     array($this,'edit_field_callback_id_company_add'));
```

and then:

```
 function edit_field_callback_id_company_add($value, $primary_key){

    $this->db->where('id',$value); //Where id is the primary key for company table
    $company = $this->db->get('company')->row();

    return '<div id="field-id_company" class="readonly_label">'.$company->name_company.'</div>';
 }
```

There is at the documentation an article that explains how to use callbacks at: http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/tutorial_using_callbacks

If you like you can also use the field_type method ( http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type ) with field_type = readonly

As for the default value functionality there is an issue at github for that: https://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud/issues/138

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my select is always the same, the selected element isn't the id_company

Comment: Then you just need to add the id_company at your fields method. For example $crud->fields('field1','field2','id_company'); . This should work for you ;-)

Comment: uhm sorry but this string isn't put inside the callback but after the call for example, in this case I have many field into my view ("notes,id_order ...) but only the field id_company must have a default value

Comment: Can you please update your Question with the full function that you use please, so I can understand better? Thanks.

Comment: I have update my question, I have cut most of part because is very long but I think this is the main part

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer. For now there is not such functionality in grocery CRUD to actually have "set_relation" field AND "readonly" the same time. Hope it works.

Comment: No errors it doesn't show.. I ahve called a function into the model to retrieve information  like your code (because query is better to do in the model) but nothing

Comment: Did you replace with:  $crud->callback_edit_field('id_company',                   array($this,'edit_field_callback_id_company_add')); as well? Weird!!!

Comment: Ok last turn, I've updated my answer as well, I hope this will work as expected this time ;-)

Comment: Something is better, I haven't the select but I have an inout text ok, but the input is empty, I have already the name of the company intio a variable but seems that doesn't call the callback to insert the name into the value

Comment: What version of grocery CRUD do you use and what Codeigniter version?

Comment: Aha! There you go. The problem is your grocery CRUD version. I was sure that this bug was fixed long time ago! I think if you download the latest version 1.3.3 you will not have this problem. I think from version 1.2 to 1.3.3  they are not any renames so it will probably just work for you without any issues. Of course make sure that you have a back-up first before the update :-)

Comment: I don't think that you will have any problems with the update. The update will probably be smoothly. But of course I am NOT Guaranteeing  anything, that's why it is always better to have a backup before the update. Just make sure that the new assets folder,model,library and config is included as well.

Answer (score -1):

here decided this problem. i hope it help for you. http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1846-setting-default-value-for-field-type-and-set-relation/

Comment: please don't answer questions with only links; if the link ever rots, your answer becomes useless.  links are great but answers should stand on their own.

Comment: OK i see your idea. but, i test. report is successful. it is happy code for Grocery crud.